# formatting quotes with list environment

Tags: spacing, lists, quoting

heyho,

I am typesetting a book and the publisher requires special formatting for quotes. I found a solution by using the list environment, although the line spacing is not yet perfect.
so this is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[DIV=11,11pt,headings=small,titlepage,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}[2016/06/14]
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{inner=5cm, outer=5cm, top=6.5cm, bottom=5.5cm}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Times New Roman}       \let\sfdefault\rmdefault    
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{zitat}{
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0,4cm}
\setlength{\itemindent}{-0,4cm}\small}
}
{\end{list}}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{zitat}
Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das    bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{zitat}

\blindtext

\begin{zitat}
 Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{zitat}

\begin{zitat}
Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{zitat}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Please note that I compile with LuaTex.

The horizontal spacing is perfect as it is (left 0,4cm, right 0cm), I need to somehow define the *vertical* (or *line*) *spacing*, which should be 0,3cm to both the main text up and down. I don't fancy the list environment, so any other code solutions will be fine. 
Thanks so much for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent what already exists! The `quoting` package will make you happy:

```
\documentclass[DIV=11,11pt,headings=small,titlepage,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}[2016/06/14]
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{inner=5cm, outer=5cm, top=6.5cm, bottom=5.5cm}
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Times New Roman} \let\sfdefault\rmdefault
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small, leftmargin=0.4cm, rightmargin=0cm, vskip=0.3cm}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
%
\begin{quoting}
  Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{quoting}

\blindtext
%
\begin{quoting}
  Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{quoting}
%
\begin{quoting}
  Repräsentation ist nun nicht mehr der passive Ausdruck von etwas, das bereits besteht, sondern wird selbst zu einer sozialen Praktik, die an der Herstellung des von ihr Repräsentierten mitbeteiligt ist.
\end{quoting}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

If you want the first line indent, just add an blank line between the environment and the text above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, your solution fits perfectly fine!! :) and yeah, you are so right, why inventing something new - but for some of us (like, eh, me) documentations are not easy to comprehend sometimes and I just didn't know how to cope with my spacing problem after consulting the quote documentation... So thx again!

Comment: Interestingly, to begin the quote with a square bracket - which can be necessary because the quote needs to be integrated/slightly changed - doesn't work out, because the brackets just disappear and the dots appear centered in a line before. So, if you need to start the quote with "[...] blablabla" you shall use the math encoding $[...]$ Unfortunately, this doesn't work with a letter as in: "[a]ufgrund der blablabla" because the a in square brackets becomes somehow italicized. How can I possibly prevent these errors?

Comment: @Franzi: The best way to learn how to use a package is to experiment on small examples when you're not sure to fully understand.  For your bracket problem, it isn't really one: it comes from the fact the environment accepts optional arguments (I put them in the preamble via `\quotingsetup`). Same problem in a `tabular` when  you want to begin a new row with a bracket: it conflicts with the optional argument of `\\ `. Workaround: write `{}[…]` instead of `[…]`.

Comment: Yep, that's it, again. Thanks for your advice. I guess I am not the most passionate "experimenteur" when it comes to LaTeX stuff.

Comment: The point is not to experiment for pleasure, but when one has a problem to solve, it's  better to have a feeling of the ins and outs of a package.